# Windows Phone 8.1 missing PdfDocument API from Windows Store

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Windows Phone 8.1 is missing the Windows.Data.Pdf.PdfDocument API from Windows Store apps. What are my alternatives? Will this get added soon?

Comment: What is the scenario? If you are just trying to have a user view the file you can launch another app for that

Comment: In my experience, users feel cheated if you open another app to open PDF files.

Comment: Unfortunately short of writing your own viewer that is your best bet on WP. If all the apps are going to have to do the same thing, then hopefully users will be used to it and they won't feel cheated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in a comment above, this is not currently supported. I have received a comment from a Microsoft employee on MSDN which says:

> You can launch PDF files into the default PDF app or find a 3rd party
>   PDF control. We can't comment on future versions of the OS.

This hints at future support. In theory it should be easy for them as Windows Phone 8.1 is now the same platform.

Comment: Currently converting PDF files to images can be done using paid components, one of them I'd recommend is Apitron PDF Rasterizer. Has free trial, used by existing Windows Phone PDF viewers. One of the advantages is that it supports text search and returns found text coordinates, while MS alternative does not.